# Prove that if $A\neq B$ then $\exp(A/n) \neq \exp(B/n)$ for some $n\in \mathbb N$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A \neq B \in M_{n\times n}$ be linear maps. 
I'd like to prove that there exists $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $e^{A/n} \neq e^{B/n}$.

I tried assuming that  $e^{\frac{A}{n}} = e^{\frac{B}{n}}$ for every $n\in \mathbb N$ and get using uniqueness of a solution to an ODE that $A = B$, but that didn't work out. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Thank you Travis! I also found another solution:

$A = Ae^{At}|_{t=0} = \lim_{t\to 0} {\frac{e^{tA} -1}{t}} = Be^{Bt}|_t=0 = B$
by definition of the derivative (and $e^{\frac{1}{n}A} = e^{\frac{1}{n}B}$).

Comment: The question perhaps confusingly uses $n$ in two different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** More or less by definition, the pushforward of the exponential map $$\exp : M_{n \times n} \to GL(n, \Bbb R)$$ at $0$ is the identity map:
$$T_0 \exp = \operatorname{id}_{T_I GL(n, \Bbb R)} .$$
In particular, there is some open neighborhood $U$ of $0$ such that the restriction $\exp\vert_U$ is a diffeomorphism $U \to \exp(U)$.

> On the other hand, for any $A, B \in M_{n \times n}$, there is some $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{N} A, \frac{1}{N} B \in U$.

All of this works just as well if we instead work over $\Bbb C$.

Comment: So basically the inverse function theorem, thanks!

Comment: @Trouble Yes, exactly. And you're welcome!